# Persisting dictionary value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application with the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> mappings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Byte[] destination = new Byte[fileData.ContentLength];
                        fileData.InputStream.Position = 0;
                        fileData.InputStream.Read(destination, 0, fileData.ContentLength);
                        var returnValue = GUIDGenerator(destination);
                        mappings.Add(fileData.FileName, returnValue);
                        return Json(new { success = true });
                    }
```

Every time the user selects a file and uploads it, I want to add its name and GUID into a Dictionary type "mappings". But With every upload, the mappings re-initializes itself. How do I persists values in it?

Comment: Have you tried moving the mappings collection outside of your action method?

Comment: will not work either - making it static will help (a bit) but you know - your "application" is not running consistently without configuring the IIS-host to be "non-scalable"

Answer (score 1):

if you really want it persistend and scalable you will have to do this in a database. But using the Session-object or other cachich-mechanisms may work for you as well.

BTW: moving the dictionary into the controller won't work as well because the controller is created everytime a method on it is called (yeah you can change this, but this is the default behaviour).

I would consider using a database.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make a static variable at the top of the class:

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> _mappings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

But that will only live with that session on the server that code ran in.  You might be better off saving and reloading that data from a database.